# How can I get total count of likes, dislikes and shares for each book Id from a table in mongodb using aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a table named histories. here is a sample of documents,

{
"_id": "6354e4210490e6f3dd109fb7",
"type": "like",
"bookId": "6329af1b1c67cc8eaf26fe42",
"userId": "635122ea40ef5d60e653fc9e",
"createdAt": "2022-10-23T06:50:09.166Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-10-23T06:50:09.166Z",
"__v": 0
},

{
"_id": "6354e4210490e6f3dd109fb9",
"type": "share",
"bookId": "6322db5464c70448ad0282d4",
"userId": "6301e9f243719de7e0637acf",
"createdAt": "2022-10-23T06:50:09.167Z",
"updatedAt": "2022-10-23T06:50:09.167Z",
"__v": 0
}

now i have to show a list of distinct bookId with its total likes, shares and dislikes count using aggregate in mongodb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
db.histories.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$bookId" ,
            likes: {
                "$sum": { $cond: { if: { "$eq": ["$type", "like"]}, then: 1, else: 0 }}
            },
            dislikes: {
                "$sum": { $cond: { if: { "$eq": ["$type", "dislike"]}, then: 1, else: 0 }}
            },
            shares: {
                "$sum": { $cond: { if: { "$eq": ["$type", "share"]}, then: 1, else: 0 }}
            },
        }
    },
])
```